# MySQL table with multiple values in a field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table in which multiple values occurs in some rows. In the example below such values are separated by vertical bar (`|`).

```
+---------+------+
| cui     | type |
+---------+------+
| 100     | A    |
| 101|102 | A    |
| 103     | B    |
| 104|103 | C    |
+---------+------+
```

I wonder how to retrieve only the first value if multiple values are present. For example, the table above should be returned as

```
+---------+------+
| cui     | type |
+---------+------+
| 100     | A    |
| 101     | A    |
| 103     | B    |
| 104     | C    |
+---------+------+
```

Any suggestions are greatly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `substring_index()`

```
mysql> select substring_index('101|102','|',1);
+----------------------------------+
| substring_index('101|102','|',1) |
+----------------------------------+
| 101                              |
+----------------------------------+
```

So the query becomes

```
select substring_index(cui,'|',1) as cui,
type
from table_name
```